# HtmlWebpackPlugin plugin doesn't output anything

Tags: javascript, webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I need to minify 2 JS files and inline one of them into HTML template.
I have the following directory structure:

```
- src
---- page.html
---- script-to-inline.js
---- script.js
- webpack.config.js
```

And the following webpack config:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('dotenv-webpack');
const InlineScriptWebpackPlugin = require('dotenv-webpack');

module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,
    mode: 'production',
    entry: {
        script: './src/script.js',
        'script-to-inline': './src/script-to-inline.js',
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
    },
    plugins: [
        new Dotenv(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            inlineSource: './src/script-to-inline.js',
            template: './src/page.html',
            filename: 'page.html',
        }),
        new InlineScriptWebpackPlugin({
            names: ['script-to-inline'],
        }),
    ],
};
```

Build output is the following:

```
Hash: bb94c50e294f070b4fd1
Version: webpack 4.12.0
Time: 118ms
Built at: 2018-06-20 13:58:48
                      Asset      Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
tracking-script-injector.js  1.24 KiB       0  [emitted]  tracking-script-injector
                tracking.js  1.28 KiB       1  [emitted]  tracking
[0] ./src/tracking-script-injector.js 971 bytes {0} [built]
[1] ./src/tracking.js 630 bytes {1} [built]
```

It looks like `HtmlWebpackPlugin` doesn't even try to read the template I pass to its options.

What should I change to make plugin process the `page.html` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not working because the require statement is not referencing correctly to the plugin (which is weird too because webpack did'nt yell at you).

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('dotenv-webpack');
```

It should be:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
```

Comment: No worries, everybody does that